# PrintWriter constructors

Tags: java, printwriter

I've listed below the 8 constructors of `PrintWriter` class.
`PrintWriter(File file)`, `PrintWriter(File file, String csn)`, `PrintWriter(OutputStream out)`,
`PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)`,     `PrintWriter(String fileName)`,
`PrintWriter(String fileName, String csn)`,     `PrintWriter(Writer out)`,
`PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush)`.

Questions:

1. If there's no PrintWriter contructor that takes PrintStream, then how come we can write a statment like  I've written below?
2. If there's no PrintWriter contructor that takes BufferedWriter, then how come we can write a statment like I've written below?

   ```
         PrintWriter writer1 = new PrintWriter(System.out);

         PrintWriter writer2;
         writer2 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(outdir, reportFileName))));
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Study what Polymorphism is

Comment: A PrintStream is an OutputStream and a BufferedWriter is a Writer.

Comment: Not polymorphism, as such, but rather see the hierarchy structure of `PrintWriter`. What does it extend and what other classes are in the structure. [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html) extends `Writer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible because [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) inherits from FilterOutputStream and the latter again from OutputStream.

[image]

A [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) inherits from Writer.

[image]

Writer and OutputStream are possible variables in the [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) constructors. The big topic, what we are talking about here, is inheritance. There is a [good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990093/java-inheritance) for this.