# How to separate a common code from implementation specific code?

Tags: java, oop, conditional-statements, factory

I have something like this:

```
switch(type){
    case "CAR":
       return new Car();
    case "BIKE":
       return new Bike();
}
```

Now, there is a requirement, to add a common API for both to check if input type is valid, only when validateFlag is true.

Can you suggest some design here? What's the best to go with?

I am thinking of something like:

````
if(flag== true)
  return new Validator();
switch(type){
    case "CAR":
       return new Car();
    case "BIKE":
       return new Bike();
}```
````

Comment: What is the return type of the method? @Turtle seams to think it's a common superclass of `Car` and `Bike`, which makes sense, but returning a `Validator` doesn't make much sense if you can also return a `Car` or a `Bike`.

Comment: If it's not a type of car or bike, how do you think we should separate this, we can add a if else block while calling this itself, but the idea is to avoid if else's and instead use some design pattern

Comment: I don't understand your question

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990093/java-inheritance) here. Have a look at the sample code below.

```
class Vehicle {
    protected boolean mIsValid;
    
    public Vehicle() {}
    
    public boolean isValid() {
        return mIsValid;
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car() {
        super();
        mIsValid = true;
    }
}

class Bike extends Vehicle {
    public Bike() {
        super();
        mIsValid = false;
    }
}
```